# Simply sqlalchemy filter not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, updating

Select all works like this:

```
q = session.query(products)
```

Now I want to add a WHERE filter, so I am trying:

```
q = session.query(products).filter_by(stock_count=0)
```

I get an error saying 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'class_manager'.

Not sure what the issue is?

**Update**
The column seems to be mapped fine, as when I do:

```
q = session.query(products)

for p in q:
   print p.stock_count
```

It outputs the value.

But if I do:

```
p.stock_count = 6
```

**I get an error also, saying: "can't set attribute"**

So I can query for it, but adding the column as a filter, OR setting the value causes an error.

**Strange no?**

Comment: I tried:  session.query(products).filter_by(products.stock_count==0) but I get an error:  'table' object has no attribute 'stock_count'.

Answer (score 2):

You may be trying to use the orm against a bare Table object.

This code works on 0.5 (the one in base centos 6.2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

db = create_engine(localopts.connect_string)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)

Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(bind=db)

class some_table(Base): 
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['table_name']

session = Session()

for row in session.query(some_table.username).filter_by(username="some-user"):
    print row
```

Comment: This is awesome and shows me exactly what I want SQLSoup to do but can't find because there is next to no documentation. Thanks for providing the bridge into getting SQLAlchemy doing what I needed so neatly.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a .all() after your filter_by:

```
q = session.query(products).filter_by(stock_count=0).all()
```

Comment: yeah - I verified that on my end as well - can you post your `products` class in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Literal Sql](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/ormtutorial.html#using-literal-sql)? I've had the same error message but when I used literal sql it was gone.

So for your example it would be something like:

```
q = session.query(products).filter('stock_count==0')
```

Comment: If you go with `.filter()`, you can use just `.filter(product.stock_count == 0)` instead of literals.

Answer (score 0):

`filter_by()` works with a keyword dictionary, you actually want to use `filter()`. Additionaly you can't just use `stock_count` (probably, you didn't show your table definition code), you have to use `products.stock_count` or possibly `products.__class__.stock_count`. So Try: 
`q=session.query(products).filter(product.stock_count==0)`